# How to use Start-Job in windows command while maintaining the state of current session

Tags: windows, multithreading, powershell, start-job

I am trying to run multiple jobs in parallel using Start-Job cmdlet. I have huge environment setup which is ignored because Start-Job runs the jobs in new session. Is there any way to maintain the environment settings. I want it to fork basically.

Answer (score 0):

The `Start-Job` cmdlet has switch `-InitializationScript` that is used to pass an initialization script that could contain the same env setup as the main session.

As per documentation:

> -InitializationScript
>
> Specifies commands that run before the job starts. Enclose the commands in
> braces ( { } ) to create a script  block.
>
> Use this parameter to prepare the session in which the job runs. For example, you can use it to add functions, snap-ins, and modules to the session.